# Different Get methods in Node-Express Rest API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I have been creating a website with Mean stack and I stuck at some point. I have a mongo db database and I am currently getting each file from database (to show them on Main page) with my Rest Api which is build with Express.

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://username...', ['myApp']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/myApp', function (req, res) {
    db.myApp.find(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

app.get('/myApp/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db.myApp.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    })
});

app.listen(3001);
console.log('Server running on port 3001');
```

There is 2 get method and I can understand that because they have different parameters. So when I call them from controllers, there is no problem because if I provide id, it will call the second get method. But for example I want to use something like this in my website;

```
app.get('/myApp', function (req, res) {
    db.myApp.find({}).limit(2).skip(0, function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

This get method have no parameter like the first get method in server.js but they do different jobs. This is limiting my search with 2 file. How can I use different get methods like this in my Mean Stack application?

This is my code for calling get method from my main controller. How can I make sure to call specific get method? Thanks..

```
$http.get('/myApp').success(function(response) { .. });
```

Comment: try reversing their order

Comment: As @malix pointed out, try revising the order. A request like `'/myapp/foo'` will trigger your first `/myapp` route handler rather than the second one.

Comment: @AshleyB what does revising the order mean ? Can you provide a code piece if you don mind or explain more detail. Are you trying to say use different names in methods like; '/myApp/GetAll' and '/myApp/Limit2' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible. Somehow you need to distinguish between your 2 intentions, either by giving the endpoints different names (like you already suggest in your comment) or by providing for example a query parameter so you could do a call like:

```
$http.get('/myApp?limit=2').success(function(response) { .. });
```

When limit is omitted, you could return all results.

Something like:

```
app.get('/myApp', function (req, res) {
   var limit = req.query.limit;
   if (limit === undefined) {
      // Return everything
   } else {
      // make sure limit is some valid number
      // ... and do a mongo query limited to this number
   }
});
```